# Is there tooling to maintain internal typescript references?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015, resharper, resharper-10.0

When using Typescript in Visual Studio in a project with internal modules (namespaces) and using gulp to build, concat and minify the files, I have to maintain references to other files correctly using `/// <reference path="..." />` to ensure that the concatenated files are ordered in respect to the their dependencies to avoid that files load before their dependencies.

In a larger project with many classes, it's cumbersome to keep all references up to date by looking at a specific file, traversing to it's dependencies in the solution explorer and drag them into the file to create a reference-tag.

However, both Visual Studio and Resharper are able to correctly identify the source file for a type as F12 immediately takes me to it. So my tooling knows very well where stuff is.

Is there a way for Visual Studio and/or Resharper to automatically maintain the references within a file, or at least to offer me a shortcut to automatically insert a reference for a type just like I can press F12 to open the file?